# page template: want to use django's AdminCalendar

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I want to use the AdminDateWidget to display the date for my custom page.

I cant figure out how to get template engine to render the AdminDateWidget correctly.

Right now it simply shows the datefield as text.

So this is what i have so far:

So I create a form and a model where I specified this:

```
class Author(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")
    if False:
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _("Rich Text Author page")
            verbose_name_plural = _("Rich Text Author pages")

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    dob=DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
```

This is the view:

```
# Create your views here.
@processor_for(Author)
def author_form(request, page):
    form = AuthorForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form processing goes here.
            redirect = request.path + "?submitted=true"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
    return {"form": form}
```

Now the trouble is in the template:

How do i create a template that will display that widget correctly?

```
{% load i18n admin_modify adminmedia %} {% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }} 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% admin_media_prefix %}css/base.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% admin_media_prefix %}css/widgets.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}js/core.js"></script> {{ form.media }}


{% endblock %}

h1>{{ page.author.title }}</h1> <p>{{ page.author.dob }}</p> askdmfksasaidjf
```

Please help.

Thanks for your time and kind concern.

Jenia